# Getting javascript error: element is not defined

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, javascript

I am trying to verify carousel has auto flash and manual selection options. For manual option I checked the slick dots are clickable. For auto flash option I am checking the style animate-repeate is greater than 0. I am using JavaScript to check CSS styles. I'm getting element is not defined in below line.

```
js.executeScript("const repeatValue = element.style.animate-repeat;");
```

Page class function:

```
public MasterBannerPage verifyClickAndFlash() {
        
        //locate slick buttons
        List<WebElement> carouselButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='slick-dots']/li[@role='presentation']/button[@role='tab']"));
        
        WebDriverWait wt = new WebDriverWait(driver,1);
        
        //verify slick dot are clickable
        for(WebElement button: carouselButtons) {
        
        wt.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable (button));
        
        }
        
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        //verify auto flash
        js.executeScript("const element = document.querySelector('main-carousel');");
    
    js.executeScript("const repeatValue = element.style.animate-repeat;");
    
    //verify auto flash
    js.executeScript ("repeatValue > 0;");
    
    //boolean result = (boolean) js.executeScript ("document.getElementsByClassName('main-carousel').style.animate-repeat>0;");
    
    boolean result = (boolean) js.executeScript ("repeatValue > 0;");   
        System.out.print(result);
        
        //Assert.assertTrue(result);
        
        //return new Master Banner page object
        return new MasterBannerPage();      
    }
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: element is not defined
```

Style:

```
:root {
    --animate-duration: 1s;
    --animate-delay: 1s;
    --animate-repeat: 1;
}
```

What shouldI do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was as mentioned in the error. I was using an undefined element. element should be a web element not a constant. All I had to do locate web element using selenium and get all css styles related to element not only the styles mentioned in html style attribute. Then get the property value I needed.

Below is the code that worked for me.

```
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        
        
        WebElement carousel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slick-track']"));
        
            
        String script = "var s = getComputedStyle(arguments[0]);"+
                        "var v = s.getPropertyValue('animation-iteration-count');"+
                        "return v;";
        
        System.out.println(js.executeScript(script, carousel));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "element is not defined" is occurring because you are trying to access the element variable before it is assigned a value. You need to retrieve the carousel element and assign it to a variable before trying to access its style property.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("const element = document.querySelector('.main-carousel');");
js.executeScript("const repeatValue = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('--animate-repeat');");
boolean result = (boolean) js.executeScript("return repeatValue > 0;");
System.out.println(result);
```

This code will retrieve the carousel element using the `document.querySelector` method, and then it will retrieve the value of the `--animate-repeat` style property using the `window.getComputedStyle` method. Finally, it will return the result of `repeatValue > 0` as a boolean value.